# Problem with resources folder in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've got this piece of code in my MainActivity.cs of my Xamarin.Android project.

```
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
```

Somehow I get the error: Resource.Layout doesn't contain a definition for Toolbar. I don't understand why, because I've got the Toolbar.xml file in my layout folder. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding solutions?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I can always try it again.

Comment: Could you show the Toolbar.xaml? Did you change its content ?

Comment: Well, I just copied the lines which are in the Toolbar.xml file of another project and somehow that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try unload and reload project.

Note : I am designing views in intelliJ Idea(Community version is free) and transfer xmls to Visual Studio later.  I think Xamarin designer is still has problems.

Comment: Well, that wouldn't work for me because I'm making a cross-platform app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just copied the lines which are in the 'Toolbar.xml' file of another project and somehow that worked.

Nevertheless, I want to thank everyone for their help!

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```